# Can we extract just the outside surface of a 3D model?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, nurbs-surface

I am new to using Blender and wanted to know if this software can serve my purpose before jumping into using it.

I have CT(Computed Tomography)-scanned an object and exported the mesh into a PLY file. However, since this object has other objects inside, this mesh has both internal and external surfaces. However, I would only like to extract the surface area on the outside where it touches the air or delete the internal surfaces.

Because my object seems very complicated, the surface of the outside can often be connected to the internal object as well.

Previously, I have tried Meshmixer to hollow it out however, it did not work as it thinks the internal surface is still a surface.

Is there a way to solve this using Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+internal+faces

Comment: Thanks so much. 'Internal geometry' was the key word. I will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

sorry LTTP but I solved this problem with meshmixer and netfabb. First, repair part in netfabb. Then, in meshmixer use "separate shells" and delete the internal parts that separate. If necessary, simplify slightly the model via "make solid" tool, and repeat. Eventually you will obtain one main surface and hundreds of internal "bubbles" that can be deleted.